# How can Y create a menu item by code on Joomla 4?

Tags: joomla4

I can create menu items in joomla 3 with the install/update script (example here : https://webkul.com/blog/menu-item-joomla-rebuild-automatically/) but it doesn't works in Joomla 4... How can I do in joomla 4? I saw the class Menufactory\createMenu() but I can't find any examples...
Thank's